# UIWebView Zoom to Rect where tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, svg, uiwebview, zooming

All,

I am displaying a SVG file in UIWebview, I am doing that, I am able to get Xvalue and YValue from the node i clicked. now based on the values i want to Zoom to particular value, I tied with UIScrollView Zoomtorect, but not able to get it.

How can we achieve

Comment: Hi, Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8392926/3660980

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `UIWebView` property`scalesPageToFit` to `YES`.